# MVC - Name of Html Helper change and get prepended with item when using foreach loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I have a page that show a list of checkboxes, for showing my checkbox on page I use the code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
      <td>
       @Html.EditorFor(
       model => item.IsSelected, new { htmlAttributes = new { @name = "IsSelected" } })
      </td>
}
```

now my problem is when the page got rendereded the name of checkboxes is getting prepended with item therefore the name is `item.IsSelected` instead of `IsSelected` and as a result binder can't bind it to my ViewModel, I've tried setting its name but no use, is there a way I can keep the name the same or use some trick to bind it to my ViewModel without using plain Html?

**Edit:**
My ViewModel:

```
    public int NewsLetterId { get; set; }
    public string NewsLetterEmail { get; set; }
    public string NewsLetterSubscriberName { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public int? PriCatIDfk { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("PriCatIDfk")]  
    public virtual PriCat PriCat { get; set; }

    public int? SecCatIDfk { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("SecCatIDfk")]  
    public virtual SecCat SecCat { get; set; }
```

Comment: You know, that you don't need `foreach` if you using `EditorTemplate`? Show your template and `VeiwModel` please

Comment: I'm not using EditorTemplate, it there a way around it without using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use `EditorFor`, try `CheckBoxFor` instead:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
      <td>
       @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model[i].IsSelected)
      </td>
}
```

You should use `for` loop instead `foreach`, becouse it's only way to make right names for binding without **Editor Template**.

Actually i suppose this will work too:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
      <td>
       @Html.EditorFor(x => Model[i].IsSelected)
      </td>
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now the name become `[0].IsSelected` but the binder recognize it, do you think I should use Editor Template for this or it would be an overkill and what you've suggested here will do?

Comment: it's ok to use `for`, if you don't have complex View logic.